# How to SEO a .onion website?

Tags: onion-services, web-proxy

I know most of the people try to hide their hidden service from search engines but in my case I want to optimize it's rank when searching for it or for tags it contains in search engines (both deep web search engines and clear net search engines).
I mentioned clear-net as I saw that some of the hidden services are searchable from Google with ".onion.to" or ".onion.ws" proxy sites.
Also I have to say that I added my hidden service into some deep web lists and some tor search engines which have manual website submission, but not successful, when I search for my website, even after I search for exact url the search engines can't find it.
I have to add that it's 24 hours past since I created and submitted my .onion site.
I also tried google search console and added the  tag into first page of my onion site and also added the proxified site (MyWebsite.onion.to  or MyWebsite.onion.ws) inot google but google can't detedct it. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also tried google search console and added the tag into first page of my onion site and also added the proxified site (MyWebsite.onion.to or MyWebsite.onion.ws) inot google but google can't detedct it.

It's not that Google can't detect it, it's that they don't try. You can't even find facebook's .onion service there. Why? Because their search spiders are not using Tor and Google is pretty anti-Tor. You can try submitting your page to privacy respecting engines sites like [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/newbang) but I don't know how much luck you'll have if they can't index the site.

Another option is to advertise it on social media. https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/ keeps lists of submitted onion services.

Comment: I tried using onion.ly instead of onion.ws and now google also indexed my website!

Comment: If you're a big enough website (>10,000 users), then you can add yourself to this list of popular `.onion` sites https://github.com/alecmuffett/real-world-onion-sites